# Native function or logic to test if string is a single real number

Tags: matlab

I have a decent number of edit boxes in a GUI. The majority of them must take in a single real number. I'd like to return an `errordlg` if the input is not a single real number.

I've been using `str2num` with some additional checking like `isreal` when getting the the string of the edit box. An example is shown below:

```
    total_units_buffer = str2num(get(handles_gui.edit_totalunits,'string')); 
    % Check if input is number and real
    if (~isempty(total_units_buffer) && isreal(total_units_buffer))
        % Do stuff
    end
```

Usually, the output is `[]` when the input is not a number, so I've been using `isempty` as a test as well. However, I discovered recently that if there's an `i` in the input, like `10i`, it will read the number as an imaginary number, instead of returning `[]`. I also recently discovered if you put a space in the input, like `10 10`, then `str2num` will read it as two numbers, which breaks the logic I have now. Furthermore, `NaN` will also be read as a number.

Basically, I keep discovering these little things that require me to update my testing for a single real number.

So I was wondering, is there a native function to test whether a string is a single real number in Matlab? Or, conversely, is there a guaranteed logic that absolutely ensures the number will be a single real number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be enough

```
str =  %// your String 

x = str2double(str)
y = isfinite(x) && isreal(x)
```

you could also consider something like this:

```
y = ~all(x-real(x))
```

I just have seen, that both methods fail for an input like `str = '5,0'`. It would be **50** what is certainly not desired. You could avoid this by adding the line:

```
str = strrep(str,',','.')
```

Comment: Ok so `isfinite` is better than `isnan` for my case because it covers both `NaN` and `inf` string inputs, correct? I'm still not sure if this logic is exhaustive though.

Comment: I couldn't imagine a case where it shouldn't work. And yes `isfinite` also covers the case when the input is `inf`, which `~isnan` doesn't. In general you have various options for the first case (isfinite should cover everything), but there is no way around `isreal`.

Comment: Hmmm... Ok I'm feeling good about this answer but I'm going to wait a bit before accepting to see if anything else pops up. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at my other suggestion, but there is actually no point ;)